# Push notifications filtering troubles (Pushwoosh)

Tags: ios, push-notification, filtering, pushwoosh

I'm having some troubles with notifications when my app is closed.

I use the pushwoosh iOS sdk on my project (free account) and I'm sending a message like this:

```
{  
"id": 1,  
"pais": "España",  
"es": "message",  
"date": "20-12-2013"  
}
```

When my app is open I can filter the notification and only show "message" on the alert but when the app is on background or is closed it shows all the message in the json format instead of filtering them.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app is closed or in background the iOS itself (not the code!) shows the push notifications message. That's why you see the behavior as explained above. You need to use custom data for deep linking. That's the only way to do it on iOS.